# css javascript style sheet disabled?

Tags: javascript, css

what does it mean to have a style sheet disabled?

I just realised that its possible when i visited this page.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLStyleElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable styles by setting the `disabled` property on the element that loaded them (either a `style` element for inline styles, or a `link` element for linked stylesheets). When disabled, a stylesheet's rules aren't applied.

Example:

CSS:

```
<style id='style2'>
  p {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<p id ='theParagraph'>Click this paragraph to toggle the <tt>style2</tt> styles.</p>
```

*(I know, I know, `tt` is deprecated.)*

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('theParagraph').onclick = function() {
  var style = document.getElementById('style2');
  style.disabled = !style.disabled;
};
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ojisu6)

Answer (score 3):

The stylesheet included in the web page would be disabled if the attribute `disabled` is added in the `<link>` tag...

This is mostly used when the web pages apply multiple themes...and has something of a sort of a Themeroller

Answer (score 2):

It means its style declarations contained within will not be applied.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/qH9mH/).