# How to override main.css with an alternate stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I have a main.css with 550 rows. Theoretically I would like to create an alternate stylesheet for the visually impaired users. The problem is, that the contrast.css contains only 4 rows:

```
body{
background-color:#000;
color:#ff0;
}
```

So now it overrides the background color and text color in the body, but only that part. I have background-images, border-images and everything is the same, because it doesn't disable the other parts of the main.css. How can I disable the main.css? I don't want to place a button or a link or something on the page, in firefox there is an option for switching between stylesheets. How can I do this only with CSS?

Comment: If the page is references classes in `main.css` what would those elements use if you disable it?

Comment: Are you saying for the alternative CSS, you *only* want those 4 lines of CSS (and ignore the entirety of the previous 550?)

Comment: You could disable the other CSS file with some help of JavaScript by setting the `disabled` attribute on the `<link>` tag. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5776324/2373114)

Comment: @Kimmax It doesn't work when a user switches in firefox between the 2 stylesheets [Firefox switcher](http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2008/10/switch_site_styles_with_css_page_style.jpg)

Comment: @DA. Yes, but I think it's not possible with only 4 rows, so I'm waiting for a great idea, that shows me, how to override or reset or ignore or make the other parts of the main.css disappear.

Comment: If you want to disable an entire CSS file, you need to use JavaScript to 'detach' it from the page. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Actually, this has already been documented quite well. Just google "Swap CSS file with JS" for examples. Here's one: http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I am making the assumption that the user is able to select the sort of view with a click of a button. In that case you could use Js to add class or remove class from the body element.
So you layout out will be like this:

```
    <body class="default">
       ....
    </body>
```

This could be you basic setup, and use the class default as a prefix(sort of) for all your default styles, i.e `.default.background{}`

If the user chooses to view in the visually impaired mode, remove the class on click of the button. The styles for the visually impaired mode will be `.background{}`. That way you wouldn't need two sets of stylesheet but achieve the same result.

Comment: Removing every class, type selector and id is impossible.

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting you. Do you mean that the main.css is un editable? You only remove the class default from the body. If the .default is removed, all the styles starting with the class .default will be ignored, leaving you with styles for the visually impaired(which had been over written by the default styles).

Comment: @darksoul90 here is codepen i mocked up to show you what i mean: http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/oaFpG/ . This this something that you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood it. The next question is: how do you know when a user switches in firefox between the stylesheets? [Firefox stylesheet switcher](http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2008/10/switch_site_styles_with_css_page_style.jpg)

Comment: If you want to support firefox, then you could add an additional stylessheet with the styles for the visually impaired. This functionality only exists in firefox I believe. Since it going to be a small file then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This would work except that you'd have to preface all of your CSS selectors with a particular class, which would be a bit messy.

Comment: Well true, but if you are using sublime it is quite easy to achieve https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZnVBVaQpWs . Yes its messy but its a simple solution that will work.